# convert digits to special format

Tags: r

In my data processing, I need to do the following:

```
    #convert '7-25' to '0007 0025'
    #pad 0's to make each four-digit number 
    digits.formatter <- function ('7-25'){.......?}
```

I have no clue how to do that in R. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

digits.formatter <- function(string){
  str_vec = str_split(string, "-")
  output = sapply(str_vec, function(x){
    str_padded = str_pad(x, width = 4, pad = "0")
    paste(str_padded, collapse = " ")
  })
  return(output)
}

digits.formatter(c('7-25', '8-30'))
# [1] "0007 0025" "0008 0030"
```

The `pad=` argument in `str_pad` specifies whatever you like to pad, whereas `width=` specifies the minimum width of the *padded* string. You can also use an optional argument `side=` to specify which side you want to pad the string (defaults to `side=left`). For example:

```
str_pad(1:5, width = 4, pad = "0", side = "right")
# [1] "1000" "2000" "3000" "4000" "5000"
```

Comment: this is exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In base R, split the character string (or vector of strings) at `-`, convert its parts to numeric, format the parts using `sprintf`, and then paste them back together.

```
sapply(strsplit(c("7-25", "20-13"), "-"), function(x)
    paste(sprintf("%04d", as.numeric(x)), collapse = " "))
#[1] "0007 0025" "0020 0013"
```

Comment: Assuming every element has just one `-`, there's `s = type.convert(do.call(rbind, strsplit(x, "-"))); sprintf("%04d %04d", s[,1], s[,2 ])` to simplify to a single sprintf call.

Comment: @d.b Just thought about that on the ride home.

Answer (score 0):

We could do this with `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("(\\d+)", ~sprintf("%04d", as.numeric(x)), v1)
#[1] "0007-0025" "0020-0013"
```

If we don't need the `-`,

either use `sub` after the `gsubfn`

```
sub("-", " ", gsubfn("(\\d+)", ~sprintf("%04d", as.numeric(x)), v1))
#[1] "0007 0025" "0020 0013"
```

or directly use two capture groups in `gsubfn`

```
gsubfn("(\\d+)-(\\d+)", ~sprintf("%04d %04d", as.numeric(x), as.numeric(y)), v1)
#[1] "0007 0025" "0020 0013"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("7-25", "20-13")
```